# Does a negative line bundle admit a non-trivial global section?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

As well known, there are many global sections for a positive/ample holomorphic line bundle over a complex manifold. Then it is natural to ask

**Whether  a negative line bundle admit a non-trivial global section?** (For projective space, the answer is apparent)

Any suggestions is welcomed.

Comment: What is a negative line bundle?

Comment: A line bundle with a nonzero global section is effective. This is usually the opposite of negative.

Comment: Kodaira vanishing (a line bundle is called negative if its dual is positive)

Comment: Also, ample line bundles need not have any nontrivial global sections

Comment: You can always pass to a multiple and such that an ample line bundle has a global section though, right? If $L^{-1}$ is positive and $s\in H^0(X,L)$ is nontrivial, then there's some $N$ with nontrivial $t\in H^0(X,L^{-N})$, while $s^N \in H^0(X,L^N)$. Then $s^Nt\in H^0(X,\mathcal O_X)$, and so must be trivial, so $s$ could not have been nontrivial. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DevlinMallory Thank you for your idea. However, $H^{0}\left(X, \mathcal{O}_{X}\right)=\mathbb{C}$ when $X$ is compact,  while the triviality of $s$ means zero.

Comment: @YangMills Thank you for this important warning. I alway keep in mind that  there are many global sections for a positive/ample holomorphic line bundle. Can you give an example to your claim that   ample line bundles need not have any nontrivial global sections.

Comment: ah, apologies for the confusion- by trivial I meant constant (and I’m assuming X is projective). as to your question about ample bundles with no nontrivial sections, just take any degree-1 line bundle on a higher genus curve.

Comment: @DevlinMallory  Apologies for my deficiency  on the knowledge of the subject.  What does the degree mean for a holomorphic line bundle on a general compact manifold? (I only know the degree of a hypersurface or a line bundle in projective space). Where can I find the fact that degree-1 line bundle on a higher genus curve admit no nontrivial sections? Thank you a lot!

Comment: A degree -1 line bundle on a curve is not ample. But you can find a genus 2 curve $C$, and points $p,q,r\in C$ so that $p+q-r$ is not effective (see Hartshorne Ch. IV) -- then $L=\mathcal O_C(p+q-r)$ works.